# GPO Windows Server 2008 Not Applying on Windows 7 Client

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I am attempting to create a proxy settings GPO in Windows Server 2008 via the Group Policy Management application. When I set user configurations from the administrative template (eg Disable changing proxy) and do a gpupdate on the Windows 7 client, the return says it failed, check the event viewer. The event viewer states the file specified cannot be found registry.pol. When I check the location mentioned the file it is looking for is not there, but when I remove the admin template config the error goes away but the GPO settings do not get applied on the Windows 7 client (eg the Proxy settings).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use RSOP. and check if that works on that machine, check that the windows 7 is legal and legit. and check event viewer with https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-event-logs-errors-and-6871f163

Look for errors in the Event logs in server and computers

Comment: Thanks, I am getting event ID 1096. Looks like GPM isn't creating the GUID folder. Tried recreating the GPO several times and no GUID folder is created.

Comment: Well that's the problem then, check the permissions of the sysvol.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816750%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Dont forget to add it as an anwer if that solved your issue